# show drop menu outside the sidebar that has a scroll, but still in the same position as the anchor

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html

Like facebook, when hover over the image of the friend it shows drop menu out side the left sidebar of friends,

I gave the drop menu position absolute with respective to the app itself (position: relative), but the problem is when scrolling down the menu appear below its anchor tag, how can I fix it ?

here is the sample of the code that I have,
can I implement this with pure css or I need JS ?

```css
.App {
 position: relative;
}
nav {
 overflow: auto;
 max-height: 700vh;
}
.dropMenu {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div className="App">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a onClick={this.showDropMenu}> ... </a>
   </li>
   <div className="dropMenu"></div>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I had also this problem, I added an answer tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: sticky;`

```
.App{
 position: sticky;
 }
nav {
 overflow: auto;
 max-height: 700vh;
}
.dropMenu {
 position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way you can do it using only CSS. You may have to implement other behaviors if you want to have a fully functional dropdown-menu.

```js
$(".nav li").on("mousemove", evt => {
  const li = $(evt.target);
  const dropdown = $(evt.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
  let liTop = li.offset().top;
  liTop = liTop < 0 ? liTop * -1 : liTop;
  dropdown.css('top', liTop + li.height());
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
ul li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
ul li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
ul li .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
     <a href="">Lorem 1</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
        Lorem 1 <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam exercitationem facilis neque quos laborum deleniti rem in distinctio cum atque recusandae earum architecto veniam maiores dolores, ad nihil molestiae excepturi.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="">Lorem 2</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
        Lorem 2 <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam exercitationem facilis neque quos laborum deleniti rem in distinctio cum atque recusandae earum architecto veniam maiores dolores, ad nihil molestiae excepturi.
    </div>
    
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="">Lorem 3</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
        Lorem 3 <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam exercitationem facilis neque quos laborum deleniti rem in distinctio cum atque recusandae earum architecto veniam maiores dolores, ad nihil molestiae excepturi.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="">Lorem 4</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
        Lorem 4 <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam exercitationem facilis neque quos laborum deleniti rem in distinctio cum atque recusandae earum architecto veniam maiores dolores, ad nihil molestiae excepturi.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="">Lorem 5</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
        Lorem 5 <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam exercitationem facilis neque quos laborum deleniti rem in distinctio cum atque recusandae earum architecto veniam maiores dolores, ad nihil molestiae excepturi.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem here that I have a scroll properties in nav,
and I need the drop menu to appear outside it ?

Comment: Same here -  "position: absolute;" does the work but when you scroll the bar it's not scrolling and the element is staying in the same position.

Comment: @RichardSocker , exactly, I need the drop menu to appear outside the nav as it done above, hover when scrolling the nav down the menu appear below its button alot

Comment: I see. It happens because the browser is positioning the dropdown-menu related to body. To achive what you want, the solution would be dynamically positioning the dropdown and watch the onscroll event of the navbar using JavaScript. Are you using jQuery on your project?

Comment: @CristianoSoares , 
No I don't use it, however now I'll try to figure out a solution with pure css,
but if there isn't any one I'll try with that,
if you know how to implement it with react put it in the solution please.

Comment: @mustafaalfar, I've just updated the code snippet with a solution using jQuery. I hope it inspires you making your own in pure JavaScript. Cheers!